# Oracle - Getting Select Count(*) from ... as an output parameter in System.Data.OracleClient

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Greetings all,

I have a question.  I am trying to build a parametrized query to get me the number of rows from a table in Oracle.  Rather simple.  However I am an Oracle newbie..

I know in SQL Server you can do something like:

`Select @outputVariable = count(*) from sometable where name = @SomeOtherVariable`

and then you can set up an Output parameter in the System.Data.SqlClient to get the @outputVariable.

Thinking that one should be able to do this in Oracle as well, I have the following query

`Select count(*) into :theCount from sometable where name = :SomeValue`

I set up my oracle parameters (using System.Data.OracleClient - yes I know it will be deprecated in .Net 4 - but that's what I am working with for now) as follows

```
IDbCommand command = new OracleCommand();
command.CommandText = "Select count(*) into :theCount from sometable where name = :SomeValue";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

OracleParameter parameterTheCount = new OracleParameter(":theCount", OracleType.Number);
parameterTheCount .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(parameterTheCount );

OracleParameter parameterSomeValue = new OracleParameter(":SomeValue", OracleType.VarChar, 40);
parameterSomeValue .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameterSomeValue .Value = "TheValueToLookFor";
command.Parameters.Add(parameterSomeValue );
command.Connection = myconnectionObject;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
int theCount = (int)parameterTheCount.Value;
```

At which point I was hoping the count would be in the parameter `parameterTheCount`  that I could readily access.

I keep getting the error ora-01036 which http://ora-01036.ora-code.com tells me to check my binding in the sql statement.  Am I messing something up in the SQL statement?  Am I missing something simple elsewhere?

I could just use command.ExecuteScaler() as I am only getting one item, and am probably going to end up using that, but at this point, curiosity has got the better of me.   What if I had two parameters I wanted back from my query (ie: select max(ColA), min(ColB) into :max, :min.....)

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of the ADO does not need the colon `:` configuring `OracleParameter`.

Instead of:

```
new OracleParameter(":theCount", OracleType.Number);
```

try

```
new OracleParameter("theCount", OracleType.Number);
```

Anyway, I think you have to use the `ExecuteScalar()` function of the `IDbCommand` and avoiding use of `into` (which I'm not sure it's valid on this context). I mean:

```
IDbCommand command = new OracleCommand(); 
command.CommandText = "Select count(*) from sometable where name = :SomeValue";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

OracleParameter parameterSomeValue = new OracleParameter("SomeValue", OracleType.VarChar, 40);
parameterSomeValue .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameterSomeValue .Value = "TheValueToLookFor";
command.Parameters.Add(parameterSomeValue );
command.Connection = myconnectionObject;
int theCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

*Disclaimer*: The code have not been compiled, and may be have any little error.

**Update**: If you take a look on the Oracle [SELECT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2065646) syntax, you will see that The `SELECT INTO` sentence is not recognized. But it's valid in PLSQL syntax as you can see [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm#sthref3047). You can try one of the following to see if it works (not tested):

```
command.CommandText = "begin Select count(*) into :someCount from sometable where name = :SomeValue; end;";
```

Comment: Greetings,  

I tried removing the :'s in the name on the parameter definitions.  No effect.  

I did end up using ExecuteScaler.  I am still interested (out of curiousity) if it is possible to do what I was trying to do.

The problem seems to be with the output parameter definition.  When I remove that parameter and the :theCount from the query it works like a charm.

Comment: Updated with a try to SELECT INTO

Comment: Yep, adding the begin and end did it, it now works and I can get the value out as an output parameter.  Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have a trailing space in the parameter name for `parameterTheCount`.

**Edit**

Now remove the colons from the parameter names in the constructor to `OracleParameter`.

Comment: Tried, no effect.  As I mentioned in the comment to FerranB.  The issue is with the defintion of the output parameter :theCount.